# How to use KVO as an alternative to custom delegates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

I am an iOS programmer. I just started learning coding for MAC OSX . But now  I am having tough time coding for MAC OSX . The terms KVO and Bindings making my life tougher. There are document available but none of the document gives complete idea to me .

My question is can I use KVO  as an alternative to custom delegates . If so how to achieve this?

For eg, say I have a Class A and Class B, where A is the initial class . Now suppose my control moves from Class A to Class B , and if I want to achieve something from back in class A I can do the same very easily using custom delegate to pass the control to class A.

How to achieve this using KVO ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The Apple docs do a pretty good of covering this subject I thought.

Comment: You can use KVO in iOS, it's not restricted to OS X.

Comment: What do you mean by "my control moves from class A to class B"?